# boto3 client cannot serialize correctly

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

So I'm new to both python and AWS/Lambda and I'm having some trouble. I want to read cloudwatch logs using boto3 but it doesn't work. When I run the code below in AWS, I get the following error:

```
An error occurred during JSON serialization of response: AttributeError("'CloudWatchLogs' object has no attribute 'start_query'",) is not JSON serializable

import boto3
import time

boto_client = boto3.client('logs')


def start_query(query):
    current_time = time.time()
    response = boto_client.start_query(
        logGroupName='app-start-logging',
        startTime=current_time,
        endTime=current_time - 86400,
        queryString=query
    )
    return response
```

I have followed the documentation on https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.start_query

Comment: whats the output from pip freeze?  I was able to reproduce your error.  I setup a virtualenv and installed boto3 and your code seemed to be happy.  Try virtualenv it might help pin point the problem.

Comment: I cannot run the code locally as I haven't set up my machine to connect. I'm only trying to run this directly on AWS lambda

Comment: maybe add ```import botocore```

Comment: Didn't seem to work sadly.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that **CloudWatch Logs Insights** was introduced on November 27, 2018 ([Document History - Amazon CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/DocumentHistory_cwl.html)).

The version of `boto3` currently supported into AWS Lambda is `1.9.42` ([AWS Lambda Runtimes - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html)).

Boto3 v1.9.42 was released on Nov 10 2018 ([boto3 · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/boto3/#history)).

Therefore, the version of boto3 supplied in AWS Lambda (as at the day I'm writing this) **does not support CloudWatch Logs Insight**.

You can upgrade the version of boto3 being used in an AWS Lambda function. See: [Lambda Functions with Newer Version of boto3 than Available by Default – M&S Consulting – AWS, Salesforce, Oracle, Hadoop](https://www.mandsconsulting.com/lambda-functions-with-newer-version-of-boto3-than-available-by-default/)

Comment: Hmm, intreresting, when I print the version of boto4, it looks like I have 
boto3 version:1.7.74
botocore version:1.10.74

Comment: On your own computer? Then you should update with `pip install boto3 --upgrade`.

Comment: No, on aws...

I tried doing the thing descibed in the blog. It actually worked, but now  I cant edit code inline because the project is 50MB big...
On my local machine I got 1.9.142

Comment: Why is my boto3 version on amazon super old? I removed my added boto3 package and tried running with python 3.7 instead as it should support the newer boto3 package: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html
but it yields the same result as I had before.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "on amazon", but if you mean on an Amazon EC2 instance, then it would depend upon the AMI used to launch the instance. You can upgrade the version, as mentioned above. It might also be getting confused between python2 and python3, so you might need to use `pip3`. It is always safest to create a Virtual Env for python to avoid version conflicts.

Comment: Yeah well I run the code as Lambda, not an EC2 instance.